# How to send Philips Hue activity data to a Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, philips-hue, ifttt

Is there an easy way to have my Philips Hue export all its activity as a log to a Google Sheet?  I looked on ifttt but all I could see were triggers for activating Hue lights based on certain criteria.  Is there any easy way to get bulb on/off times logged to a Google Sheet?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a script that can do this. First start by reading the Philips Hue API, and then the Google Script documentation. Philips Hue has the ability to output to a JSON. You can program your script detect changes in the JSON and do something as a result of that change, in your case create a new entry based on the change.

## Hue API

https://developers.meethue.com/documentation/core-concepts

## Google Script

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/

## GS JSON Import

https://medium.com/@paulgambill/how-to-import-json-data-into-google-spreadsheets-in-less-than-5-minutes-a3fede1a014a